# Why does "Evaluate Expression" in the debugger shows NPE but the actual code runs fine in Intellij?

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea, playframework, jvm

I'm running a Play web application in IntelliJ, using SBT on debugger port 9999.

I have a `User` model and a `Info` model which form a one-to-one relationship. Each `User` object contains an `Info` object.

When I am running the application and visit the webpage, in IntelliJ's debugger, when a `User user` is fetched, it's `info` field is populated only with the `id` field for that info entry. Therefore, when I do `user.info.address.equals()` in `Evaluation Expression`, the debugger gives NPE since any other fields in `info` are not populated thus null.

```
User user = User.findById(id); // user.info only has id populated, with everything else null
String addr = user.info.address; 
if (addr.equals(someVariable)) // NPE in Evaluate Expression, but no bug when it actually runs
{
  // Do something
}
else
{
  // Do something else
}
```

However, when I click `Resume Program` and just let the code go, instead of throwing NPE, the application actually runs through and different fields in `info` are displayed correctly.

So here's what's confusing me. If it's a lazy fetch (so `info` in not populated until we actually need it), then where does the fetch happen? The code above is right next to each other so no extra database query should happen in between I suppose?

Even if there is some query happening, why does `Evaluate Expression` not pick it up but simply says NPE?

Comment: NPE would only take place if the code is trying to use a null pointer. Given the code above, even if 'address' was null, the code is still legal, it just puts null in 'addr'. Could be that the debugger is trying to do something silly like .toString() on the null address, but that's just a guess.

Comment: @AliCheaito But why when I resume the program from that breakpoint, it runs thru without exception? Shouldn't `Evaluate Expression` be consistent with what actually happens in code?

Comment: What happens in the code is mostly up to you, the programmer. In the two lines included above, you asked Java to read a null variable and place its value in 'addr'. That does not cause an NPE. If you were to do String addr = user.info.address.toString(); then you would be in trouble. The Evaluate Expression is a function of the debugger and you'd have to look at the implementation of that debugger to know what goes on there.

Comment: @AliCheaito Sorry apparently I missed a part. What I am referring to is the `equals` method call after setting the null pointer. See my update.

Comment: ... that should cause an NPE at runtime. Did you try printing 'addr' before the if statement to confirm that it is null?

Comment: @AliCheaito `addr` is null in the debugger so I also think it should throw NPE. But at runtime when I resume from the breakpoint it just goes through, and gives the right logic (If what `addr` is supposed to contain matches `someVariable` it goes into if, otherwise else). My guess is that some db querying happens underneath the scene when the code actually calls `equals()` on `addr`, but also doubt this can ever happen in Java.

Comment: @OneZero Ebean works modifying the bytecode of the entities, so I guess when you compile that code it will be modified to load the data when needed. Probably running in "Evaluate Expr" will execute your code without modifications...